# Cypress gets 401 error and logs out during the test (session issue probably)

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm facing an issue which I couldn't solve yet and wanted to get some opinions from you. I've a selector which has two options in total and I'm using `select` to switch between them. I wasn't sure about the code so I added `url` check as well, which works successfully.

However, the page loads with the first selection so the api call has already been made, but, in the second part (items section) when I select `Items` it throws 401 error and logs out which breaks all the following tests.

What can I do/improve here? This flow works perfectly on my local but Cypress fails.

Things I've tried:

- selecting using `0` and `1` without value names.
- tried with {failOnStatusCode: false}.
- couldn't use Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce (since it's deprecated).
- I also tried this one as well here; `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8aoVh6IdCg`

Thanks in advance!

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot2]

```
it('verifies there are only orders, drafts and/or return orders on all orders grid', () => {
  ordersPage.ordersSelector().trigger('click')
          cy.get('select').select('orders').should('have.value', 'orders');
          cy.url()
            .should('include', 'orders');
    const orderNumberPrefix = ['DRAFT-', 'SO0', 'S0-', 'R0']
    cy.get('.ag-center-cols-container div[row-index]')
      .each($row =>{
        const $col = $row.find('[col-id="orderNumber"]')
        const orderNumber = $col.text().trim()
        const correctOrderNumberPrefix = orderNumberPrefix.some(prefix => {
          return orderNumber.startsWith(prefix)
        })
        expect(correctOrderNumberPrefix).to.be.true;
      });
    })

it('verifies there are only orders on items grid', () => {
  ordersPage.ordersSelector()
          cy.get('select').select('items').should('have.value', 'items'); //fails here
          cy.url()
            .should('include', 'items');
    const orderNumberPrefix = ['SO0']
    cy.get('.ag-center-cols-container div[row-index]')
      .each($row =>{
        const $col = $row.find('[col-id="orderNumber"]')
        const orderNumber = $col.text().trim()
        const correctOrderNumberPrefix = orderNumberPrefix.some(prefix => {
          return orderNumber.startsWith(prefix)
        })
        expect(correctOrderNumberPrefix).to.be.true;
      });
    })
```

Comment: Does that exact page rely on a logged in user?

Comment: Yes... I need to preserve cookies, local storage or the whole session. I'm trying to saveLocalStorage, restoreLocalStorage, etc. Still couldn't fix it yet. I'm using Cypress v10.

Comment: Resolved the problem via implementing `npm i --save-dev cypress-localstorage-commands`. Then did the following:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.restoreLocalStorage();
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    cy.saveLocalStorage();
  })
```

For more information: https://dev.to/javierbrea/how-to-preserve-localstorage-between-cypress-tests-19o1